# Are 済む・澄む・住む cognate?

Tags: etymology, false-etymology

Which of these words are cognates (share a common etymology)?

- 住【す】む ("live") (rarely 棲む or 栖む)
- 澄【す】む ("clear") (rarely 清む)
- 済【す】む ("end")

According [gogen allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/su/sumimasen.html) and several dictionaries such as the [大辞泉【だいじせん】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/smp/leaf/jn2/120156/m0u/), `済む` derives from `澄む`. Perhaps the English expression `I believe that the issue is #cleared up#.` helps to illustrate this relationship.

The 広辞苑【こうじえん】 dictionary (6th ed.) speculates that `住む` derives from `巣【す】` ("nest"), and lists `巣にいる` as the first (ie oldest) meaning. It also quotes the following phrase from the 古今和歌集【こきんわかしゅう】 providing a certain plausibility for the suggested etymology: `花【はな】に鳴【な】く鶯【うぐひす】、水【みづ】に住【す】むかはづの声【こゑ】を聞【き】けば`. Although, it is not quite clear to me why `住む` here would mean `巣にいる` specifically and not `to live` in general.

This suggest that 住む is unrelated to 澄む・済む. However, I did not find any information regarding the origin of 澄む.

Are the above mentioned sources correct? Is 澄む cognate with 住む, or are they not related at all?

Comment: Although 澄む does contain an **up** (登), my initial intuition is quite the opposite -- all three すむ (住, 澄/清, 済) have **down** as in _settle down_ (落ちつく) in common. The Chinese character 住 means _to stay_ or _to stand_ (居る, 止まる). Maybe すむ is also related to やむ, やすし (安, 靖) and やすむ. The Kanji 安 and 靖 both have the meaning of _to stop/to be stable_.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible suggestion to me. Whether or not this is the actual origin of all three words, I could understand how all three meaning are derived meaning are derived from."settle down". I think we can ignore the kanji altogether as this is about native(?) Japanese words.

Comment: For what it's worth, 澄 apparently derived from the idea that dirty **water**, when you let it **rest**, the clear water will end up at the **top**, and the dirt will sink down to bottom -- it **settles down.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much as described in the question comments by Yang Muye and blutorange, 1) all of these *sumu* verbs derive from Old Japanese in ways that make the kanji irrelevant to a discussion of etymology, and 2) all of the modern senses of *sumu* arise from an underlying idea of **to settle**.  Interestingly, the English term **to settle** covers most of the same meanings as the Japanese *sumu*: to **live in a place**, to **become clear** (such as water), to **finish**, to **be fully paid** (such as an account), etc.

(This same etymology was briefly mentioned [in this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/difference-between-the-words-for-living-residing-%E4%BD%8F%E3%82%80-%E6%A3%B2%E3%82%80-%E6%B3%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B-%E6%9A%AE%E3%82%89%E3%81%99#answer-17350).)